# UINavigation Controller inside Tab Bar Controller Issue

Tags: ios, storyboard

My current storyboard looks like the following: [image: Click here to see screenshot]

The problem is that I don't know what relationship the "Login View Controller" should have with the other views. As a result, when I build the project - "View Controller" comes up as a black void, [image: Click here to see what I mean].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your tabBarController and type in an identifier, say yourVCID

[image]

You can then reach your view controllers like so:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourVCID") as! UITabBarController
```

// Above line will give you the address(reference) to the View controller that has an id "yourVCID". This is where you want to go.
here self is the Login View Controller(from where you want to go). StoryBoard is the storyboard that contains the view Controller represented by self.

```
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

// Above line will present the controller and this controller will originate from self (Login View Controller) in this case

This will automatically present the Home screen (View Controller) of your Tab bar controller

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! After adding the tabBarController identifier, I inserted your snippet of code into my ViewController.swift viewDidLoad() function. Unfortunately I received an error - "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'LoginViewController'" and the problem still persists.

Comment: I have updated the answer. This should work.. I had to use the storyboard, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Thank you for the update! The code did indeed work. If you don't mind me asking one last question, when the view controller is presented, it gets stuck in a infinite loop (the VC keeps on representing itself). What would be the source of this?

Comment: That's weird. i cant picture that. Is there any way you can provide more details? Can you show me where are you puttin this code? maybe you're running it in a block that is an infinite loop

Comment: In my ViewController.swift file - `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //myLocation()
        
        let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourVCID") as! UITabBarController
        
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }`

Comment: Okay.. you need to put this code in Login View controller.

Comment: Oh my - my bad! Yes you're absolutely right, I must of had a brain fart. I now got everything working! Thank you very much for your help Mr. Thakur!

Comment: No problem. Please see my update. And glad I could help.